# How to correctly prepare an IStream object in order to use it between different threads?

Tags: c++, com, thread-safety, streaming

In a multi-threaded c++ project (working on Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2019), I open an IStream COM object in a dedicated thread, let's naming it *Thread A*, with the following code:

```
...
::CComPtr<IStream> pStreamThreadA;

HRESULT hr = pShellItem->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_Stream, IID_IStream, (void**)&pStreamThreadA);
...
```

Once opened, I want to read its content in a second thread, let's naming it *Thread B*. As it's a COM object, I'm aware that it's hazardous to try to use it in the *Thread B* while it was created in the *Thread A*. For that reason I Marshall it with the following code:

In *Thread A*:

```
...
const HRESULT hr = ::CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(IID_IStream, pStreamThreadA, &m_pMarshall);
...
```

In *Thread B*:

```
...
::CComPtr<IStream> pStreamThreadB;
const HRESULT hr = ::CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(m_pMarshall, IID_IStream, (void**)&pStreamThreadB);
m_pMarshall.Release();
...
```

But this doesn't work. When I try to seek in my stream in the *Thread B*, e.g. with the following code:

```
...
const LARGE_INTEGER zero = {0};
ULARGE_INTEGER      pos;
const HRESULT       hr = pStreamThreadB->Seek(zero, ::STREAM_SEEK_CUR, &pos);
...
```

the code execution get stuck in the `Seek()` function and never returns. For that reason I assume that the stream pointer became invalid (i.e dangling).

On the other hand, and paradoxically, if I bypass the Marshaling code above and I use the stream pointer directly between the threads, barely respecting the usual lock mechanisms, all work fine. But I'm aware that this is very unsafe and not recommended.

So can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong in the above code, and why my Marshaled stream lead to an invalid pointer?

Comment: Where did `pShellItem` in the first fragment come from? Did you also create it on Thread A, or did you pass it down from another thread? If the latter, was it marshalled properly?

Comment: `m_pMarshall.Release()` is wrong; the pointer was already released once by `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` (hence the name). Make it `m_pMarshall.Detach()`

Comment: Most likely, thread B gets a proxy to Stream object living on some other thread. `Seek` call attempts to marshal to that thread, but that thread is not accepting incoming requests for whatever reason (e.g. it's an STA thread that doesn't pump messages in a timely manner).

Comment: Why don't you do everything in a given thread? Pass only the IShellItem's PIDL to the other thread (PIDLs are by design cross thread/process/machine), re-open it from there and read the stream from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I unfortunately could not find the reason why this happens, but I assume that @IgorTandetnik is right, as indeed my thread is an apartment thread, it's probably something disrupting the message loop. I reorganized my code to avoid the Marshaling operation.